# How do I create a non Gregorian based customized 2000AD - 8000BC 10,000 year clock and lunisolar calendar?

Tags: datetime, time, calendar

I trying to figure out how to create a clock and lunisolar calendar that can extend back by at least 10,000 years calculated down to the millisecond.  I want to make it in html and excel.  But the problem is that I don't know how to change the rules of how time works e.i the length of the second, minute, hour, day, month, year, leap year, and year week.

Comment: I think You must choose either excel or html (+javascript), then You ask for "how time works"

Comment: You could start with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719176/algorithm-to-find-the-gregorian-date-of-the-chinese-new-year-of-a-certain-gregor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719176/algorithm-to-find-the-gregorian-date-of-the-chinese-new-year-of-a-certain-gregor)